# Square root of compact positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

‎Let $T\geq 0$ and $T\in K(H)$, where $K(H)$ denotes the compact operators on $H$.

I want to show the following statement:

> There ‎is a‎ ‎compact and unique positive ‎operator‎‎ ‎‎$‎A‎$‎ so that‎ $A‎ =‎ ‎T‎^{2}‎ $‎.‎‎

Answer (score 0):

The spectral decomposition shows that there is an orthonormal sequence $(u_n) $of eigenvectors of $T$ such that

$Tx= \sum \lambda_n<x,u_n>u_n$  for all $x \in H$.

$(Tu_n= \lambda_n u_n)$

Since $T \ge 0$, we have $\lambda_n \ge 0$ for all $n$

Put $Ax:= \sum \sqrt{\lambda_n}<x,u_n>u_n$  and show, that $A$ has the desired properties.

Comment: I think this only works for the field $\mathbb C$, probably this assumption was omited in the question?

Comment: No. It works also for the field of reel numbers.

Comment: Then how do you conclude that $T$ is self-adjoint? Because your statement that $Tx = \sum\lambda_n\langle x,u_n\rangle u_n$ implies that.

Comment: We have $T \ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, so self-adjointness is part of the definition of $T\geq 0$ for you. I did some googling to find that the definitions are not all the same. For me it is simply $\langle Tx, x\rangle\geq 0$ for each $x$. There are some threads on MSE concerning this issue as well.

Comment: I consider $T$ self-adjoint as part of the definition of $T \geq 0$ as-well and I consider this as pretty natural since then the term agrees with the usual definition of positive element in a c*-algebra.